# How to select up to a maximum number of turtles using roulette wheel selection

Tags: netlogo

In my model the turtles have two sexes where the males have two potential tactics. The females count the number of males in a set radius.

I want the females to weight their probability of selecting from the group of males (without replacement) depending on the relative frequency of the two male tactics.

I already have the code for the probability of selecting from the males (`matingPoolProbAnad` and `matingPoolProbRes`) but I don't know how to implement it, though the `rnd` extension seems the way to go, specifically `rnd:weighted-n-of size agentset [ reporter ]`.

It's complicated by three things (1) the males can mate with more than one female but (2) only once with a given female and (3) females can only mate with a maximum of five males.

```
to count-mates ; ask the females to count the number of males in a 10 patch radius & then 
                ; determine the frequency of the resident males in their patch

  ask turtles with [sex = "female"]
  [
    if any? turtles with [sex = "male"] in-radius 10
    [ set potentialMates turtles with [sex = "male"] in-radius 10
       ifelse any? potentialMates with [anadromousM = 1]
    [ set FA count potentialMates with [anadromousM = 1] / count potentialMates ]
    [ set FA 0]
      ifelse any? potentialMates with [anadromousM = 0]
    [ set FR count potentialMates with [anadromousM = 0] / count potentialMates ]
    [ set FR 0]
    ]
    ]
end

to mating-pool-prob ; negative frequency dependency which is based on the number of male 
                    ; resident turtles 

  ask turtles with [sex = "female"]
  [
  ifelse (FA = 1) and (FR = 0)[
      set matingPoolProbAnad 1
      set matingPoolProbRes 0
  ]
  [ifelse (FA > 0) and (FR < 1)
    [
        set matingPoolProbRes exp(a - b * (FR - c ))/(1 + exp(a - b * (FR - c)))
        set matingPoolProbAnad 1 - matingPoolProbRes 

    ]
    [
        set matingPoolProbAnad 0
        set matingPoolProbRes  1
        ]
  ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: The mating-pool-prob block returns 2 values (that add to 1). Am I right in thinking that each female turtle calculates these based on the values in their own mating pool? In that case, I don't think you need weighted random selection - weighted random selection is to select between turtles based on their value of some attribute (eg richer have more chance). I think all you want to do is say something like "give me a 20% chance of choosing one of the A types"

Comment: Also, do your constraints change the probability of choose an A or R, or do you want to calculate the probabilities leaving in all turtles and then apply the constraints at the time of selection?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You're right, the females look in a 10 patch radius and count the frequency of each male strategy type. I use this to calculate the values in mating-pool-prob. So you would suggest a random-float or similar to get the females to select the males? On your second point, do you mean should the probabilities change once a female starts choosing? That would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example may approach what you're getting at, but obviously would need to be adapted from this toy version. This setup sprouts 75% of males with strategy A and the rest with strategy B, and gives all turtles an empty agentset of mates to start off:

```
breed [ males male ]
breed [ females female ]
turtles-own [ mates ]
males-own [ strategy ]
females-own [ max-mate-count mate-count ]

to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 200 patches [
    sprout-males 1 [
      ifelse random-float 1 < 0.75 [
        set strategy "A"
        set color orange
      ] [
        set strategy "B"
        set color violet
      ]
    ]
  ]
  ask n-of 50 patches with [ not any? turtles-here ] [
    sprout-females 1 [
      set color green
    ]
  ]
  ask turtles [
    set mates ( turtle-set )
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Use a while loop to have each female iteratively assess the strategy proportions of the males available to her, then add them to her 'mates' list. More detail in comments:

```
to choose-mates
  ask females [
    ; set a cap on possible mates for females; 5, or the number
    ; available within the radius if less than 5
    let availa-males males in-radius 10
    let n-max count availa-males
    set max-mate-count ifelse-value ( n-max < 5 ) [ n-max ] [ 5 ]

    ; Until a female has chosen up to her maximum number of mates:
    while [ mate-count < max-mate-count ] [
      ; determine which available males are not already in her 'mates' agentset
      set availa-males availa-males with [ not member? self [mates] of myself ]  

      ; assess the proportion of B strategy in remaining available males
      let prop_B ( count availa-males with [ strategy = "B" ] ) / n-max

      ; example probability choice, just meant to choose B males 
      ; with a frequency disproportionate to availability
      let proba_B ifelse-value ( prop_b * 2 < 0.6 ) [ prop_b * 2 ] [ 0.6 ]

      ; use a random float to determine which strategy type is chosen
      set mates ( turtle-set mates ifelse-value ( random-float 1 < proba_B ) 
      [ one-of availa-males with [ strategy = "B" ] ] 
        [ one-of availa-males with [ strategy = "A" ] ]  )

      ; count the current mates to break the while loop once
      ; the maximum number of mates is reached
      set mate-count count mates
    ]
    ; have the female's males add her to their own mates agentset
    ask mates [ 
      set mates ( turtle-set mates myself )
    ]
  ]
end
```

To check that 'B' males are being chosen disproportionately to their availability:

```
to check-values
  let all-mates  map [ i -> [strategy] of i ] [mates] of females
  print word "Average proportion of 'B' mates chosen: " mean map b-proportion all-mates
  print word "Actual proportion of 'B' males: " ( ( count males with [ strategy = "B" ] ) / count males )
end

to-report b-proportion [ input_list ]
  let tot length input_list
  let nb length filter [ i -> i = "B" ] input_list
  report nb / tot  
end
```

I'm not 100% sure that that's what you're after- maybe you can use the `rnd` package to clean up the loop.

**Edit in response to comment**

If you modify the end of the `choose-mates like so:

```
    ...
    ...
    ; have the female's males add her to their own mates agentset
    ask mates [
      set mates ( turtle-set mates myself )
    ]
    if n-max < count mates [
      print "Fewer available males than mates"
    ]
  ]
end
```

And your `go` looks like:

```
to go
  choose-mates  
end
```

You can run `setup` and `go` as many times as you like and you should never see the printout "Fewer available males than mates":

```
to repeat-1000
  repeat 1000 [ 
    setup
    go
  ]
end
```

I ran that a few times and never had count `availa-males` be less than the count of `mates`. However, if you add in movement without allowing the `females` to reset their `mates` agentset, you do start to see it- for example, try running this a few times:

```
to go
  choose-mates  
  ask turtles [ fd 1 ]
end
```

Now, because the turtles are moving around, you have some cases where `females` held on to their mates from the previous function call and then moved into a space where there were fewer `availa-males`. The quick and easy fix is to have females clear their mates each time. Where you do that depends on your model goals (how often do females choose mates? Do they only forget some of their previous ones? etc), but here's a very simple way:

```
to go
  ask turtles [ set mates ( turtle-set ) ]
  choose-mates  
  ask turtles [ fd 1 ]
end
```

Now you can run that as many times as you like and shouldn't see the "Fewer available males than mates" printout.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think that's the basis of what I'm going for. One thing I don't understand is how the availa-males agent-set can be smaller than the mates agent-set, surely mates is a subset of availa-mates?

Comment: @ManassaMauler - Sorry, not quite sure what you mean- `availa-males` is just the males available to a female, whereas mates is an agent-set that starts as an empty turtle set (count 0) that is iteratively increased until it is equal to the `max-mate-count`, which is 5 or the count of `availa-males`, whichever is smaller. If I am misunderstanding what you're getting at please let me know!

Comment: If I understand your code correctly the `mates` variable iteratively selects from `availa-males` because `availa-males` is ALL the males available to the female. The problem happens when I increase the size of the simulation space to 100 x 100 patches. This can result in `availa-males` being smaller than `mates` for some females.

Comment: @ManassaMauler - I suppose that could happen if you run `choose-mates`, then move females, then don't reset the `mates` agentset before reselecting- in `choose-mates` above, `availa-mates` is chosen anew each time the procedure is run, but `mates` is a turtle variable. If your females choose mates, then move, they could easily have 5 mates (leftover from the last function call) while only have 3 `availa-male` to choose from. Since `max-mate-count` is based on the `availa-male` count, the `mates` count cannot be larger than the number of `availa-male` for a single iteration.

Comment: @ManassaMauler - I've made some edits to better explain what I mean! Hopefully that helps

Comment: It seems to be working alright. Though when I reduce the range from 10 to 2 in this line of `choose mates`  `let availa-males males in-radius 2` I sometimes get the `availa-mates` to be less than `mates`. This is without any agent movement. Check it out if you have the time but the code seems to be working overall. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @ManassaMauler - Hmm... not sure what's going on there. You're using strictly the example code in my answer above? I tried 100,000 replicates with the `availa-mates` radius set to 2 and no agent movement and was not able to reproduce the error you describe- not one rep had the mates count lower than the `n-max`. Sorry I can't sort that out!

Comment: Your answer really helped sort out the model so I've marked it as correct. I've come unstuck again so if you don't mind me making a slave of you perhaps you could take a look at it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947716/how-to-create-multiple-generations-of-reproduction-where-mates-are-selected-in-t