# How to create multiple generations of reproduction where mates are selected in the population

Tags: netlogo

I have a simulation with two sexes, males and females. Females select from a group of males and produce offspring. Multiple males can mate with a single female and females produce multiple offspring. When they reproduce, the parents die but there is some inheritance of traits which are `turtles-own` variables.

I had [help here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50699599/how-to-select-up-to-a-maximum-number-of-turtles-using-roulette-wheel-selection) in getting the females to choose from the pool of available males (`availa-males`). But the problem is that the `mates` variable doesn't work after the first round of mating. It stays as an `agent-set` of length 0. Hope you can help; I can clarify if anything isn't clear.

```
to go
  if ticks mod 364 = 0 [set year year + 1]


  ask turtles [
    set mates ( turtle-set ) 
    fd 1
    set age ticks 
  ]

  ask females [
     choose-mates
    reproduce
   ]

  tick
end


to choose-mates

  ask females   [
    ; set a cap on possible mates for females; 5, or the number
    ; available within the radius if less than 5

    set availa-males males in-radius 5
    let n-max count availa-males
    set max-mate-count ifelse-value ( n-max < 5 ) [ n-max ] [ 5 ]

    ; Until a female has chosen up to her maximum number of mates:
    while [ mate-count < max-mate-count ] [
      ; determine which available males are not already in her 'mates' agentset
      set availa-males availa-males with [ not member? self [mates] of myself ]

      ; assess the proportion of B strategy in remaining available males
      let prop_B ( count availa-males with [ anadromous = 0 ] ) / n-max

      ; example probability choice, just meant to choose B males
      ; with a frequency disproportionate to availability
      let proba_B ifelse-value ( prop_b * 2 < 0.6 ) [ prop_b * 2 ] [ 0.6 ]

      ; use a random float to determine which strategy type is chosen
      set mates ( turtle-set mates ifelse-value ( random-float 1 < proba_B )
      [ one-of availa-males with [  anadromous = 0 ] ]
        [ one-of availa-males with [  anadromous = 1 ] ]  )

      ; count the current mates to break the while loop once
      ; the maximum number of mates is reached
      set mate-count count mates
    ]
      ; have the female's males add her to their own mates agentset
    ask mates [
      set mates ( turtle-set mates myself )
    ]
    if n-max < count mates [
      print "Fewer available males than mates"
    ]

      set a_threshM [a_threshM] of mates

     ]
end


to reproduce

    ask females with [count mates > 0] [hatch 2  [
    set mother myself
    set motherThresh [a_threshF] of mother
    set fatherThresh sum n-of 1 [a_threshM] of mother  
    ifelse random 2 = 1 [set breed males
                         set color red
                        set a_threshM  (motherThresh + fatherThresh) / 2 + (random-normal 0 sqrt(0.5 * Va))
                        set e_threshM random-normal 0 (sqrt(Ve))
                        set z_threshM a_threshM + e_threshM
                        set condM random-normal mu_cond  sqrt(V_cond)
                        ifelse(condM > z_threshM)  [set anadromous 0] [set anadromous 1]
                        setxy random-xcor random-ycor
                       ]

                        [set breed females
                         set color blue
                        set a_threshF  (motherThresh + fatherThresh) / 2 + (random-normal 0 sqrt(0.5 * Va))
                        set e_threshF random-normal 0 (sqrt(Ve))
                        set z_threshF a_threshF + e_threshF
                        set condF random-normal mu_cond  sqrt(V_cond)
                        ifelse(condF > z_threshF)  [set anadromous 0] [set anadromous 1]
                        setxy random-xcor random-ycor
                        ]
  ] ask mates [die]
    die]

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your female "daughters" inherit the `mate-count` from their mothers. Since `mate-count` is a logical trigger for the `while` loop in `choose-mates`, try having the daughters reset their `mate-count` when they are hatched:

```
...
[ set breed females
set color blue
set mate-count 0
...
```

Additionally, females die immediately after reproducing- the only females left after `go` has been called will not yet have called the `choose-mates` procedure.

You might also consider separating out `choose-mates` and `reproduce` into separate `ask females` calls in your `go` procedure. As it is, female one chooses mates and reproduces, which removes herself and her mates from the world. Then, female two chooses mates, which not only will not include the mates of female 1 but may include the spawn of female one. It might be better to do something like:

```
  ask females [
    choose-mates
  ]
  ask females [
    reproduce 
  ]
```